# Get most recent MySQL version's yum repository

Tags: mysql, yum

I want to automate the process of installing a database on my VMs. I also want the best and newest in my database software, so I want this automation to install the latest version of MySQL every time I spin up a new VM - at time of writing, that's MySQL 8.0. Currently, to download the repository, I do

```
$ curl https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
```

and then I install it locally with `yum`. But when MySQL 8.1 is released, I would be downloading the repo from `https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql81-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm` instead.

How can I reliably and most simply retrieve a url for the yum repository for the most recent version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here,

1.
How do you know when `mysql-8.1-community` edition is released ?

2.
Once you know what to do with it. I assume the problem you are trying to avoid is to go and click on a URL, download to machine, install the release RPM and then update/install `mysql`.

Solution below assumes `mysql` devlopers don't change the URLs for future releases.

Looking at the yum repo file, `mysql-8.0-community` corresponds to this section in `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo`:

```
[mysql80-community]
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Once you know the next version is released, appending a similar section to the repo file would let you pull the next version, e.g.,

```
$ cat /tmp/mysql81.repo
[mysql81-community]
name=MySQL 8.1 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.1-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Append the content to yum repo file and install/update using yum.

```
$ cat /tmp/mysql81.repo >> /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo
$ yum --enablerepo=* clean all
$ yum --enablerepo=*mysql* update mysql
```

Comment: A possible date for 8.1 is after OOW18, which is next week.  Meanwhile, go for 8.0.13 or whatever is the latest 8.0.